# Offline English Lexicon

Tags: offline, lexicon

I would like to download an English lexicon (dictionary) - preferably a free one. I have searched online and all I can find is software.

I am looking to experiment with making software to create and solve puzzles.

Does anyone know where I can find such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is such a thing. If you're familar with MySql database take a look here: [MySQL English Dictionary - A Full English - English dictionary in MySQL Format](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlenglishdictionary/)

Answer (score 0):

[Yet Another Word List (YAWL)](https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl) is primarily a quite large word list. It could be relevant for you. The repository contains utilities for anagrams, and the readme states it is quite usable for making word games.